# How to call View() / utils::View() in a function as part of a package?

Tags: r, viewer

I am writing a function for a package that ends with a call to `utils::View()`. The aim of the function is to do some data wrangling and then open the dataset in the Rstudio data viewer with `View()`.  If I define the function in the global environment it works fine. As an example (skipping the data wrangling part):

```
foo <- function(x) {
View(x)
}
foo(mtcars)
```

opens the dataset mtcars in the data viewer. However, once I put it in my r package and call the function as part of that package it does issue the following error:

"Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::View(mtcars) : unable to open display"

I have tried to use utils::View() or simply View(), without success. Also, I have tried it with XQuartz uninstalled and with XQuartz installed and couldn't make it work.

I am using Rstudio version 1.0.153 and
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I am grateful for any hints on how to resolve this!

Comment: In most cases, I'd probably advise not to call `View` programmatically, but rather return the data.frame and let the user call `View` if they like. It's way more useful to return something that can be stored as a variable and viewed in any fashion (in the console, via `View`, with `str`, or something fancy like `DT::datatable`).

Comment: There may be reasons to call `View` programmatically, but keep in mind what will happen will depend on the interface and OS in use. While what happens in RStudio will be consistent, on MacOS called from Terminal, I get an X11 window, and frankly can't predict what would happen on other platforms.

Comment: `View` works fine in _R Tools for Visual Studio_, but as @alistaire mentioned, user interfaces can be a bit random.  Programmatically, this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `View(df)` instead `utils::View(df)`

or try restarting the session (Ctrl +shft +F10)

then again using `View(df)`

or use `dpylr` to convert it into a table then use `glimpse`

-----------------------Code-------------------------------------------

```
install.packages("dyplr")

dplyr::tbl_df(mtcars)    #to convert data to table class

dplyr::glimpse(mtcars)
```

---